# C++ 11 lambda expression as template argument

Tags: c++11, lambda

I've seen many examples of using a lambda expression as a template argument, but when i was reading the reference page for lambda functions at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), 
it has this short sentence:

> Lambda-expressions are not allowed in unevaluated expressions, **template arguments**, alias declarations, typedef declarations, and anywhere in a function (or function template) declaration except the function body and the function's default arguments.

I was very confused, is this sentence wrong or I did not understand it correctly?

Answer (score 4):

What you can do:

```
template <class>
struct Foo;

auto l = []{};
Foo<decltype(l)> f;
```

What you cannot do:

```
template <SomeType lambda>
struct Foo;

Foo<[]{}> f;
```

In other words, the type of the lambda is a normal type like any other, but the lambda-expression itself can't be used to specialize a template. The same applies to unevaluated contexts such as the operands of `decltype` and `sizeof`.

Comment: I made a mistake, i meant to use lambda expression as function template argument. Such a use-case is very common in real-world c++ programs. The template deduction would then deduce the template parameter of the closure type of the lambda function passed in.

Comment: @sniel oh, that would be an argument to a function template then. There's no issue with them, "template arguments" specifically refer to the kind above that's inside the angle brackets :)